# Scope_identity() doesn't work properly ? How to get the identity of the last row inserted by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

basically i have a stored procedure that inserts a row into a table and i need to get the identity of that row.

I am working on a project that involves real-time data handling and I have 2 tables which have basically the same structure(schema), the only difference is that the first table only contains finished "sessions", while the other one contains only "active sessions"(ones that have not yet finished and are currently being modified in real time).

I also have another table(third table) that contains user-written comments about the sessions. The relation is a SessionID (identity) column in the table with the finished results.

Basically all sessions in the real-time table have sessionid 0(as they are currently being modified and I don't know when they are going to end). When this SP is called on an "ID", the session for that "ID" is deleted and it's moved to the table with the finished results. When the row is inserted in the finished results table, a "SessionID" is automatically added.

Right now I am using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), the SP looks like this:

```
procedure [dbo].[EndActiveSession](@ID bigint)
as begin

    declare @column1variable bigint
    select @column1variable = column1 from realTimeTable where ID = @ID

    if @column1variable > 0
    begin
          insert into FinishedResultsTable(ID, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7)
          select ID, column1, GETDATE(), column2, column3, column4, column5, column6
          from realTimeTable
          where ID = @ID and column1 > 0

          declare @SessionID bigint

          select @SessionID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

          update comments_table set SessionID = @SessionID
          where SessionID = 0 and ID = @ID
    end

  delete from realTimeTable where ID = @ID
  --the rest of the logic, that doesn't concern these tables and works perfectly fine
end
```

The problem is that it **doesn't always work**. Sometimes the comments are not pointing to the correct "Session ID"

I checked other threads, searched in the microsoft docs, etc. but couldn't find anything. This is

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you try @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE _IDENTITY ?

Comment: No, because I didn't want to risk it, it might get an identity from another row, inserted outside of the scope of the stored procedure.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Paste, the `FinishedResultsTable` table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative to using @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY is something like this -

```
create table Fred (
  Id int identity(1, 1)
  , SomeText varchar(120)
  , SomeDate datetime
  , SomeAmt float
);

declare @t table (Id int);

insert into Fred (SomeText, SomeDate, SomeAmt)
output inserted.Id into @t
select 'BILL', GETDATE(), 123.4;

select * from @t;
```

At the end you will find that the table variable @t will have one row with the newly inserted row's ID in it.

Comment: This actually works, still running simulations, but I believe this solved my problem. I am storing the newly inserted row in a temp table as per your example and disposing of the table at the end of the SP. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @RosenDimitrov.  BTW - the output clause works with the DELETE and UPDATE commands as well - Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a race condition. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` works correctly.

In the code you posted there are overlaps when the 'Session' has state in both tables (after the Insert, before the Delete). Comments can be added during that period. some will be updated, some won't. Also, because the the update needs to add a `SessionID = 0` predicate indicates that the `ID = @ID` condition is not enough to find the Session comments, further indication of race conditions. And to cap all, looks like there is no transaction to cover the work, so any intermediate error will leave state inconsistent. And there is no error checking, the `INSERT .. SELECT ...` may well insert 0 rows, generating no identity.

This looks *really* poorly modeled. Generate the unique session ID at creation, have it transfer with archival, link comments to the one session ID that never changes.

Comment: this SP is only called if there is an ID in the active table and ID is unique, so no chance of having more than 1 result. The SessionID = 0 part is not necessary, the ID=@ID is more than enough, sorry if that mislead you. 

If i generated the unique session ID at creation there might be collision when I transfer it to the finished table. Also I don't know when will each session finish, because it's based on user interaction, some might take hours, some not more than a minute, that's why i decided to do it like this.

Comment: Can you also tell me what do you mean by transferring the id with archival? I am not familiar with that and couldn't find anything on the web. All links point to data archiving. If there is a way to transfer the IDs without a worry of collision it might help